# In NgRx, why are the action-types split from the actual action-class?

Tags: ngrx

I wonder why NgRx makes an extra split between the ActionTypes and the actual Action-class?

Why don't they put the ActionType straight on the class as a static property? This way you can reference the action straight from the reducer, removing some extra abstraction layer.

Answer (score -1):

We released version 7.4 where this is supported.

[Pull request](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1654)

[Docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1704)

[NgRx: Action Creators redesigned by Alex](https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-action-creators-redesigned-d396960e46da)